# Make div stick under another div when div have reached top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `.stickyMenu` div which I sits in the middle of the page. When the `.stickyMenu` comes in contact with the bottom of `.navB`, I want it to stick there. When a user scrolls back up, I want it to unstick in its original position.

Thing is, I also want this to be dynamic because `.gapA` can be of any height (currently using an offset of `350` as an example).

So in the demo below, when the orange div scrolls to the bottom of the blue div, I want it to stick there when scrolling down, then when scrolling back up, where the grey div is present, I want it to unstick and return to its natural position.

**Current code and results:**

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
      var $el = $('.stickyMenu');
      var isPositionFixed = ($el.css('position') == 'fixed');

      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 350 && !isPositionFixed) {
        $el.css({
          'position': 'fixed',
          'top': '90px',
          'width': '100%',
          'left': '0px',
          'background': 'orange',
          'z-index': '1'
        });
      }
      if ($(this).scrollTop() < 350 && isPositionFixed) {
        $el.css({
          'position': 'static',
          'top': '50px'
        });
      }

    });

  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;

}

.wrap{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.wrap .navA {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap .navB {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 90px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
}

.gapA{
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.stickyMenu {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: orange;
}
.gapB{
  height: 1500px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="navA"></div>
  <div class="navB"></div>
</div>

<div class="gapA"></div>

<div class="stickyMenu"></div>

<div class="gapB"></div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
      var $el, nav, top, 
      $el = $('.stickyMenu');
      nav = $('.navB');
      top =  nav.height() + nav.position().top;

      if ($(this).scrollTop() >= top) {
        $el.css({
          'position': 'fixed',
          'top': top,
          'width': '100%',
          'left': '0px',
          'background': 'orange',
          'z-index': '1'
        });
      }else{
        $el.css({
          'position': '',
          'top': top,
          'width': '100%',
          'left': '0px',
          'background': '',
          'z-index': ''
        });
      }

    });

  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;

}

.wrap{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.wrap .navA {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap .navB {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 90px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
}

.gapA{
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.stickyMenu {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: orange;
}
.gapB{
  height: 1500px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="navA"></div>
  <div class="navB"></div>
</div>

<div class="gapA"></div>

<div class="stickyMenu"></div>

<div class="gapB"></div>
```